# paypal chained payment in using direct payment

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments

I need to implement the paypal adaptive chained payment in website. The payment flow should be initially the payment should go to one paypal account then from this paypal account will split the account to two another paypal account. I analyzed that there is an option in paypal to this by using paypal chained payment. But i need to implement the same chained payment in DoDirect payment that is credit card payment. my question is there any option in paypal to do the chained payment in a DoDirect payment? Or is there any way to implement the same chained workflow(chained payment) in DoDirect payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to do a chained payment through using the DoDirectPayment API.  If you are wanting to use the DoDirectPayment API you would have make multiple API calls.  So if you were wanting to collect 10.00 and then have 2 receivers each get 5.00.  You would have to make two separate API calls for 5.00 each.  The buyer would then see 5.00 charged twice on their cards, and you would also have to have permissions on each of those receiver accounts to be able to process DoDirectPayments on their accounts.  They would also have to have the service set up on their accounts.

You wouldn't be able to use the DoDirectPayment API with Adaptive Payments, but you should still be able to do what you are wanting to.  You would just use the Adaptive Payments Chained Payments and the buyers would go through the flow and use the guest checkout.  The guest checkout allows buyers to use credit cards without having to sign into a PayPal account.

Also, what some merchants do use if they are wanting to use the DoDirectPayment API, is they will receive all the funds into their account.  Then towards the end of the month, they will use the MassPay API to do the payouts to all of the other accounts.  You could even use the Adaptive Payments Pay API to send the funds out as well instead of using the MassPay API.

Comment: But when i closed check there is an option to implement it via https://www.chainedpayments.com/EZChain. Do you have any idea about how they implement it?